# I am trying to make this "fps" game, and for some reason the mouseClicked function is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, mouseclick-event

When i try to do this code for some reason this part of it: (RX1 = random x 1, RY1 = random y 1)(the "+50 part is there because the width of the rectangle is 50)

```
if(mouseClicked && mouseX > RX1 && mouseX < RX1 + 50 && mouseY > RY1 && mouseY < RY1 + 50){
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    rect(RX1, RY1, 50, 50);
}
```

does not work, the program just ignnores it, ive put it everywhere i could think of, and would appreciate someone's help, thanks!

[Here is the direct link to it](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/shooting-game/5970807040065536)

Here is the rest of the code in case you need it(everything in it works besides the if mouseclicked section

```
//random x and y variables for targets
var RX1 = random(25, 375);
var RX2 = random(25, 375);
var RX3 = random(25, 375);
var RX4 = random(25, 375);
var RY1 = random(25, 375);
var RY2 = random(25, 375);
var RY3 = random(25, 375);
var RY4 = random(25, 375);

    //the juicy stuff
    
    draw = function() {
         //coloring
     
      background(255, 255, 255);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
     
     //targets:

        rect(RX1, RY1, 50, 50);
        rect(RX2, RY2, 50, 50);
        rect(RX3, RY3, 50, 50);
        rect(RX4, RY4, 50, 50);
 
 //gun
 fill(0, 0, 0);
 
//front sight
    rect(mouseX - 5, mouseY, 10, 20);
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    ellipse(mouseX + 0.5, mouseY + 5, 5, 5);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
 //back sights
 rect(mouseX + 10, mouseY, 20, 20);
 rect(mouseX - 30, mouseY, 20, 20);
 
 //slide
 rect(mouseX - 35, mouseY + 20, 70, 50);
 
 //grip ledge
 fill(77, 77, 77);
 rect(mouseX - 35, mouseY + 71, 70, 20);
 fill(0, 0, 0);
 
 //grip
 rect(mouseX - 30, mouseY + 90, 60, 100);
 

};
//on mouse click/during shooting
    if(mouseClicked && mouseX > RX1 && mouseX <       RX1 + 50 && mouseY > RY1 && mouseY < RY1 + 50     ){
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    rect(RX1, RY1, 50, 50);
}
```

P.S. I am aware i made the last snippet only for one rectangle, not a single one works either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've gotten the program to respond on a mouse click. The issue seems to be that your if statement that checks for the mouse click is outside of the draw function, which loops forever, so it never checks the if statement. I tried putting that if statement in a mousePressed function (which gets called on a mouse click regardless of where you are in the code), and it seems to work now (or at least it executes the code inside the if statement):

```
//variables

//random x and y variables for targets
var RX1 = random(25, 375);
var RX2 = random(25, 375);
var RX3 = random(25, 375);
var RX4 = random(25, 375);
var RY1 = random(25, 375);
var RY2 = random(25, 375);
var RY3 = random(25, 375);
var RY4 = random(25, 375);

//the juicy stuff

draw = function() {
     //coloring
     
      background(255, 255, 255);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
     
     //targets:

        rect(RX1, RY1, 50, 50);
        rect(RX2, RY2, 50, 50);
        rect(RX3, RY3, 50, 50);
        rect(RX4, RY4, 50, 50);
     
     //gun
     fill(0, 0, 0);
     
    //front sight
        rect(mouseX - 5, mouseY, 10, 20);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        ellipse(mouseX + 0.5, mouseY + 5, 5, 5);
        fill(0, 0, 0);
     //back sights
     rect(mouseX + 10, mouseY, 20, 20);
     rect(mouseX - 30, mouseY, 20, 20);
     
     //slide
     rect(mouseX - 35, mouseY + 20, 70, 50);
     
     //grip ledge
     fill(77, 77, 77);
     rect(mouseX - 35, mouseY + 71, 70, 20);
     fill(0, 0, 0);
     
     //grip
     rect(mouseX - 30, mouseY + 90, 60, 100);
     
    
};
//on mouse click/during shooting
mousePressed = function() {
    if(mouseX > RX1 && mouseX < RX1 + 50 && mouseY > RY1 && mouseY < RY1 + 50){
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    rect(RX1, RY1, 50, 50);
}
};
```

Comment: Do you think its possible to make it so that once I click it once, it stays on there forever? Edit: I figured it out! I put another "draw = function() {} and put what happens into it!